# Expanding memory on an Aspire T180-OA7Z computer

Tags: memory, upgrade

My computer is displaying the error message "insufficient memory."  This is the current spec:

- AMD SEMPRON 3400 +
- 80 GB SATA
- 512 MB DDR11
- DVD RW DUAL DOUBLE LAYER

I found some 1 GB modules. How many would I need for general gaming and surfing? Are they easy to install?

Comment: desktop or laptop?

Comment: There are many different types of memory modules.  Just because you have 1 GB memory modules doesn't mean they'll be compatible with your machine, even if they have the same number of pins and physical shape.

Comment: DDR11?  Wow, and here I thought DDR3 was the newest.

Comment: This one goes up to 11

Answer (score 0):

Playing games will require you to have 4GB of memory to be installed.
I wouldn't think your system would be enough for gaming at all, I would recommend you upgrade for if you want a gaming machine, unless general gaming means flash online games? then I guess you're alright.

I would say 3GB of memory is the norm nowadays, but your system looks to be very old looking at those specs, and undoubtedly support more than the 1GB module.

Answer (score 0):

Now, its hard to give a complete answer based off the information given - a quick google suggests that the system can accept up to 4 gb of memory, and has 4 slots - you can confirm this with [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/siw-download.html)

Desktop ram is easy to install - pop the top, and snap them in place

Ram requirements depends on OS - 1gb sounds roughly enough for basic tasks on 7 and is loads on XP. Gaming performance may depend on video card and other factors too.